# Cache field / entity / node

Tags: entities, caching

I have a custom field/widget that has a format view function that is highly resource intensive.  I currently am caching the result using `cache_set()/cache_get()` inside the `hook_field_formatter_view` function for my field.

Is there a better way I could be doing this?  I tried to use `drupal_render()`'s `#cache` property and it cached the output but still ran my `hook_field_formatter_view` function.

Basically, I know how to do full page cache (for anonymous users) but how do you cache a field/node/entity (for everyone)?

Comment: This is a great question - in Drupal 6 you couldn't really (though Panels allows some granular page caching) but I don't know enough about the new Cache API to comment. Very curious to see an answer though. From a general performance note, have you see AuthCache? http://drupal.org/project/authcache

Comment: That authcache module is interesting.  It is just full page cache though (and drupal 6 only currently).

Comment: What exactly is resource intensive? Is it the loading of additional data that you need to display or the actual rendering? There is http://drupal.org/project/entitycache, but that only caches the loading of entities, not rendering..

Comment: The code inside my ``hook_field_formatter_view`` is resource intensive (not sure what that is considered).  entitycache module seems promising.

Comment: @Berdir check out my answer. There is a new module called https://drupal.org/project/render_cache which fills the void.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I currently am caching the result using cache_set()/cache_get() inside the hook_field_formatter_view function for my field

Honestly this is not a bad way to go about doing it. When you have custom logic which is resource intensive, taking responsibility for your own caching decisions is usually the right idea. Honestly, I really wish more developers would familiarize themselves with cache_get/set().

Entitycache appears to be an effort to do this generally, and over time I am sure that some best practices will emerge as more people work in this space. However as of today, for anyone looking at a similar problem-set: "Figure out how to cache it yourself" is a *good answer*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using [Render Cache](https://drupal.org/project/render_cache) module. This when used in conjunction with [Entity Cache](https://drupal.org/project/entitycache) it should complement each other well as mentioned on the project page.